# Does using Redis as a session store will mitigate session replay attacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, redis, owasp, session-store

In Ruby on Rails security docs it written that using CookieStore as the session store is open to replay attack:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#replay-attacks-for-cookiestore-sessions

1. Is it true if I only save the session_id?
2. Does changing the session store to Redis will mitigate the vulnerability? see this commit: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/commit/ba7c1764be87f272759471bde01b92dcc147e952

Comment: Do you have a user case of replay attacks ? (Because the one used in the guides is pretty unlikely)

Comment: Also Redis is server sided, to me it is necessary that the user holds its identifier in his browser... and identify to the app at every URL asked.. Maybe storing extra sensitive data to REDIS is indeed feasible. The cookie should just holds the user id, CSRF token and some non sensitive data in public cookies.